# Flattening a Javascript dictionary, preserving the nested keys

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I've methods on SO for flattening an array javascript, i.e. converting `[1,[2,3]]` into `[1,2,3]`.  But I'm looking for a concise method of flattening a dictionary while preserving the keys.  Specifically, I want a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'key1':1,'key2':{'key3':2,'key4':3,'key5':{'key6':4}}}
```

To be converted into:

```
{'key1':1, 'key2.key3':2,'key2.key4':3,'key2.key5.key6':4}
```

The exact output format (dictionary, list of pairs, etc) isn't important, as long as it clearly associates the string of nested keys with a value.  For my purposes, it's also OK to assume that none of the keys contain a `.` character, so that it can be used to denote the next key.

Comment: underscorejs.org has some useful functions for manipulating data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var keys = {'key1':1,'key2':{'key3':2,'key4':3,'key5':{'key6':4}}};
var result = {};

function serialize(keys, parentKey){
    for(var key in keys){
        if(parseInt(keys[key], 10)){
            result[parentKey+key] = keys[key];
        }else{
            serialize(keys[key], parentKey+key+".");
        }
    }
}
serialize(keys, "");
console.log(result);
```

Hope this is what you want:

```
{ key1: 1, 'key2.key3': 2, 'key2.key4': 3, 'key2.key5.key6': 4 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to the problem.

```
var myDict = {'key1':1,'key2':{'key3':2,'key4':3,'key5':{'key6':4}}};

function flattenDict(dictToFlatten) {
    function flatten(dict, parent) {
        var keys = [];
        var values = [];

        for(var key in dict) {
            if(typeof dict[key] === 'object') {
                var result = flatten(dict[key], parent ? parent + '_' + key : key);
                keys = keys.concat(result.keys);
                values = values.concat(result.values);
            }
            else {
                keys.push(parent ? parent + '_' + key : key);
                values.push(dict[key]);
            }
        }

        return {
            keys : keys,
            values : values
        }
    }

    var result = flatten(dictToFlatten);
    var flatDict = {};

    for(var i = 0, end = result.keys.length; i < end; i++) {
        flatDict[result.keys[i]] = result.values[i];
    }

    return flatDict;
}

flattenDict(myDict);
```

Comment: Does this method have an advantage over the other one?  It's much longer.

Comment: The other one relies on the value being a number - my approach does not. Also the other approach creates a global variable `result` where mine is enclosed so that the scope is not polluted.

Comment: My approach will fail if the value is an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not use global variable for storing the result.

```js
var dict = {'key1':1,'key2':{'key3':2,'key4':3,'key5':{'key6':4}}};

function flatten(obj, suffix, ans) {

  for (var x in obj) {
      var key;
      if (suffix != '')
        key = suffix + '.' + x;
      else
        key = x;
    if (typeof obj[x] === 'object') {
      flatten(obj[x], key, ans);
    } else {
      ans[key] = obj[x];
    }
  }
}
var x = {};
flatten(dict, "", x)
console.log(x)
```

Comment: So I went ahead and used your answer but modified it in case that there was an empty nested key. It would fail with something like this: 

{"a": {"b": {"": "test} } }

so I added a check to see when suffix and x are not "" and when suffix is not empty but x is

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @SPS where I take in account a scenario like: {"a": {"b": {"": "Test"} } };

```
// {"a": {"b": {"": "Test"} } };

function flatten(dict) {
    let res = {}
    helper(dict, "", res);
    return res;
  }
  
function helper(obj, suffix, ans) {
    for (let k in obj) {
        let key;
        if (suffix !== '' && k !== '') {
            key = `${suffix}.${k}`;
        } else if (suffix !== '' && k === '') {
            key = suffix;
        } else {
            key = k;
        }
        
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
            helper(obj[k], key, ans);
        } else {
            ans[key] = obj[k];
        }
    }
}
```