# How to entirely level (map / reduce / recursion) a nested object of unknown depth in the most efficient manner?

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, mapping, reducing

I would like to do something like the following but in a more large scale and efficient way. Assume I have an array of objects where ***each object needs to be leveled***/flattened.

Convert something like this ...

```
[{
  name: 'John Doe',
  address: {
    apartment: 1550,
    streetno: 167,
    streetname: 'Victoria',
  },
}, {
  name: 'Joe Smith',
  address: {
    apartment: 2,
    streetno: 111,
    streetname: 'Jones',
  },
}]
```

... to that ...

```
[{
  name: 'John Doe',
  apartment: 1550,
  streetno: 167,
  streetname: 'Victoria',
}, {
  name: 'Joe Smith',
  apartment: 2,
  streetno: 111,
  streetname: 'Jones',
}]
```

As is shown above, `address` as well is an object which needs to be leveled/flattened.

But most importantly, one does not know the object/data-structure in advance. Thus one neither knows property-names nor the depth of the nested levels.

Comment: There are no arrays in the code example. If there were you could use `.flat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"So before receiving the object you do not know much about its structure."*

The OP's main task actually is ***to level*** any given nested object-based data-structure into an object of just a single entries-level. And because one does not know anything about a data-structure in advance, one has to come up with a recursive approach.

Once implemented, such a function of cause can be used as callback for an array's [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping process.

The recursive implementation itself is based on type-detection (distinguish in between `Array`- and `Object`-types and primitive values) and on [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (key-value pairs) of an object according to the currently processed `value`'s type.

```js
function recursivelyLevelObjectEntriesOnly(type) {
  let result = type;
  if (Array.isArray(type)) {

    result = type
      .map(recursivelyLevelObjectEntriesOnly);

  } else if (type && 'object' === typeof type) {

    result = Object
      .entries(type)
      .reduce((merger, [key, value]) => {

        if (value && 'object' === typeof value && !Array.isArray(value)) {

          Object.assign(merger, recursivelyLevelObjectEntriesOnly(value));
        } else {
          merger[key] = recursivelyLevelObjectEntriesOnly(value);
        }
        return merger;

      }, {});    
  }
  return result;
}

const sampleData = [{
  name: 'John Doe',
  address: { apartment: 1550, streetno: 167, streetname: 'Victoria' },
}, {
  name: 'Joe Smith',
  address: { apartment: 2, streetno: 111, streetname: 'Jones' },
}, {
  foo: {
    bar: "bar",
    baz: "baz",
    biz: {
      buzz: "buzz",
      bizz: [{
        name: 'John Doe',
        address: { apartment: 1550, streetno: 167, streetname: 'Victoria' },
      }, {
        name: 'Joe Smith',
        address: { apartment: 2, streetno: 111, streetname: 'Jones' },
      }, {
        foo: {
          bar: "bar",
          baz: "baz",
          biz: {
            buzz: "buzz",
            booz: {
              foo: "foo",
            },
          },
        },
      }],
      booz: {
        foo: "foo",
      },
    },
  },
}];

const leveledObjectData = sampleData.map(recursivelyLevelObjectEntriesOnly);
console.log({ leveledObjectData });

// no mutation at `sampleData`.
console.log({ sampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of these objects, you can easily combine each object with its "address" property using destructuring:

```js
const myInput = [
  {
    name: 'john doe',
    address: { apartment: 1550, streetno: 167, streetname: 'Victoria'}
  },
  {
    name: 'Joe Smith',
    address: { apartment: 2, streetno: 111, streetname: 'Jones'}
  }
];

const myOutput = myInput.map(({address, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...address}));
console.log(myOutput);
```

Comment: can you check the updated question

Comment: This technique is very likely to overwrite properties at different levels that happen to be named the same, so I wouldn't use it in a general case.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return a new object that has had [its `address` property merged into it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), the address property deleted, and the new object returned.

```js
const arr=[{name:"john doe",address:{apartment:1550,streetno:167,streetname:"Victoria",a:"a"},b:"b"}];

const out = arr.map(obj => {
  const newObj = { ...obj, ...obj.address };
  delete newObj.address;
  return newObj;
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: can you check the updated question

Comment: You'll need to use some form of recursion for that. Also you would need to ensure that none of the property names are duplicates of any other property name in the nested object or they will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simply approach based on a recursive function that first converts an element to the following form and then calls `Object .fromEntries` on the result:

```
[
  ["name", "John Doe"],
  ["apartment", 1550],
  ["streetno", 167],
  ["streetname", "Victoria"]
]
```

It looks like this:

```js
const deepEntries = (o) =>
  Object .entries (o) .flatMap (([k, v]) => v.constructor === Object ? deepEntries (v) : [[k, v]])

const deepFlat = (o) =>
  Object .fromEntries (deepEntries (o))

const deepFlatAll = (xs) =>
  xs .map (deepFlat)

const input = [{name: 'John Doe', address: {apartment: 1550, streetno: 167, streetname: 'Victoria'}, }, {name: 'Joe Smith', address: {apartment: 2, streetno: 111, streetname: 'Jones'}}]

console .log (deepFlatAll (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But you do have a possible significant concern here.  If you're flattening multiple levels, it's quite possible that the different levels have nodes with the same name; most of those will be clobbered when you put the object back together.

One solution to such a problem would be to flatten to a different format.  I've seen something like this used quite successfully:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "address.apartment": 1550,
  "address.streetno": 167,
  "address.streetname": "Victoria"
}
```

If you look around StackOverflow, you can certainly find answers for how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

That isn't an array.

If you want to flatten a dictionary, do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047469/5676613

This has O(n^k) and Omega(n) time complexity where n is the size of the dictionary, and k is the depth of the dictionary (or how many nests are in the dictionary).